# MySQL select a row preceding the row with ID = X

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sorting

this is actually a sorting question almost solved thanks to other posts I've found here on StackOverflow.

basically i'm trying to bumb a row up , no need to insert it somewhere in the middle of the table and change all the following rows id's just one place up (replace order id's with previous). 
I've found a solution for this in another post WHEN the id's are known for example.

### ID | name | surname

1  | John | doe
2  | Jane | Dane

but my table has gaps and often its more like

### ID | name | surname

2  | John | doe
7  | Jane | Dane

So i can't really rely on subtracting the id by 1 and replacing row 7 with the row number 7-1.

Is it somehow possible to swwitch the row id X with the one before without knowing the other id ?

is it possible to do it SQL only ? i have an idea of php-ing it but it seems alot like a fix not a solution.

Comment: Hmm... Why do you want to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

This would work in SQL Server, I'm assuming in MySQL too:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable MT
...
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable MT2 WHERE ID < MT.ID)
```

Comment: seems good... i'll incorporate it in the switch query and let you know. Thank you very much.